# Fonts in Windows 10 are too big, even though scaling is disabled

Tags: windows-10, display, fonts

Today i did a presentation with my laptop connected to a projector, and after I disconnected it and reconnected it to my usual 1080p external monitor, I noticed that all the UI text in apps (Chrome, Visual Studio, Notepad... everything) is bigger than normal.

Here is an example of the situation in Visual Studio:

[image]

Notice how the menus and file tabs have a much bigger font size compared to the source code, usually they are more or less the same. This is just an example, but it happens in all programs.

Initially I thought that by switching displays Windows had incorrectly applied scaling and/or an incorrect resolution, however from the settings it appears that is not the case, as you can see:

[image]

I have also checked in the ease of access section of the settings, but no luck either, everything is at default:

[image]

I've tried:

- Changing the settings and then changing them back
- Rebooting/signing in and out
- Disconnecting and reconnecting the monitor

but nothing solved the issue.

Does anyone know how to get out of this situation? Or do I seriously have to factory reset just to fix this? I hope that's not the case... are there any other settings that might affect windows like this? Where should I look?

Comment: Run DISM / SFC and see if that corrects the issue.  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test

Comment: @John: I performed all the steps you suggested, but unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: Have you rebooted ?

Comment: @harrymc: you would know the answer is yes if you had read the question 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Fonts in Windows 10 are too big, even though scaling is disabled

The suggestion to run DISM / SFC did not fix the issue.

The next step is a Windows Repair.

**(1)** Try a Windows 10 Repair Install and **Keep Everything.**

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

**(2)** If a "standard" Repair Install (Keep Everything) does not fix the issue, then something more serious has damaged the OS and / or the Windows User Profile.

Either way, the most practical way forward is to back everything up and reinstall Windows 10.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I will try as soon as I finish what I'm working on.

Comment: Unfortunately system restore did not work, it failed to delete a file and rolled back :/

Comment: My answer was not System Restore.  Did you try the Repair Install?  If the Repair Install rolled back, then you do need to reinstall your operating system (second part of my answer)

Comment: In the end I ended up doing reinstalling windows from scratch, since the system recovery rollback apparently screwed some other stuff up and I ended up with lots of broken shortcuts and other glitches. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am glad the reinstall worked for you